# How to make list items scale with screensize and remain horizontal?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am making a very simple website with a two horizontal navigation lists - one at the top and one at the bottom. I want the list items in both lists to remain horizontal (by becoming smaller in size) when I make the screen smaller or view it on any other computer with smaller screen and not move on top of each other like they are doing now. I've tried changing widths and margins in percentages and auto, making things inline, but since I'm new I feel im doing something fundamentally wrong. Dont worry if the rest of the website looks crap. Im just beginning to learn HTML and CSS.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-image: url("paper.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  text-align: center;
}
.heading {
  margin: 0% 46%;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #999;
  margin: auto;
  width: auto;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41
}
.button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
.myDiv {
  background-color: none;
  margin: -20px 90px;
  height: 650px;
  border: 8px double #90EE90;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: "Arial", Times, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 50%;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%
}
li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
li a {
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 76px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <h1 class="heading">Webseite</h1>

  <button class="button">Button 1</button>
  <button class="button">Button 2</button>
  <button class="button">Button 3</button>
  <button class="button">Button 4</button>
  <button class="button">Button 5</button>

  <div class="myDiv">Was willst du machen?</div>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Salman</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">Patric</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">IMIBE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You might need to look at `media query` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp also here is another like to building navigation http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;  
}

body {
  background-image: url("paper.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading {
  margin: 0% 46%;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #999;
  margin: auto;
  width: 15%; 
}

.button:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}

.button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

.myDiv {
  background-color: none;
  margin: -20px 90px; 
  height: 650px;
  border: 8px double #90EE90;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: "Arial", Times, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    display: inline;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right:1px solid #bbb;  
    width: 20%    
}

li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
    <html>

    <head>

    </head>

    <body>

      <h1 class="heading">Webseite</h1>

        <button class="button">Button 1</button>
        <button class="button">Button 2</button>
        <button class="button">Button 3</button>
        <button class="button">Button 4</button>
        <button class="button">Button 5</button>

        <div class="myDiv">Was willst du machen?</div>

            <ul>
                  <li><a href="#home">Salman</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#news">Patric</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contact">IMIBE</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            </ul>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-image: url("paper.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  text-align: center;
}
.heading {
  margin: 0% 46%;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #999;
  margin: auto;
  width: auto;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41
}
.button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
.myDiv {
  background-color: none;
  margin: -20px 90px;
  height: 650px;
  border: 8px double #90EE90;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: "Arial", Times, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  display: flex;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 25%
}
li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <h1 class="heading">Webseite</h1>

  <button class="button">Button 1</button>
  <button class="button">Button 2</button>
  <button class="button">Button 3</button>
  <button class="button">Button 4</button>
  <button class="button">Button 5</button>

  <div class="myDiv">Was willst du machen?</div>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Salman</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">Patric</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">IMIBE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>





</body>

</html>
```